# Extending a function no longer works if the parent function has more arguments than the child, even if extra arguments have default values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, php-7.2

I've noticed a problem since PHP 7.2 whereby extending a function no longer works if the parent function has more arguments than the child, even if extra arguments in the parent class have default values.

The following fatal error is thrown:

```
Compile Error: Declaration of
WebBox\PageBundle\Form\Type\PageType::buildForm(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
must be compatible with
WebBox\FrontBundle\Form\Type\CoreType::buildForm(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options, $noSubmit = false, $submitText = NULL)
```

This is for a Symfony project whereby a form class (in this case `PageType`) extends from a shared form class `CoreType`, so many of our forms can get certain common functionality. -- This problem isn't limited to just the `PageType` class, it's just the first example we noticed.

Class `CoreType` defines a public function `buildForm` as:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options, $noSubmit = false, $submitText = null) {...}
```

Class `PageType` (and any others extending from `CoreType`) define `buildForm` as:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {...}
```

Function `PageType::buildForm()` (and others) will then typically call `CoreType::buildForm()` to finalise the form building with some common behaviour, optionally choosing to not put in a submit button (`$noSubmit`), or adjusting the submit button text for various reasons (`$submitText`). Examples:

```
parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
parent::buildForm($builder, $options, true);
parent::buildForm($builder, $options, false, $this->translate("Submit for approval"));
```

This has always worked from PHP 5.5 through to 7.1, but we're suddenly finding this is not allowed in PHP 7.2. (Can't see any mention of such a change in the [7.1 to 7.2 migration docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.php).)

Have we been doing this wrong for multiple years now, or is this a bug/deprecation in PHP 7.2?

*This isn't a major deal for us as we can easily switch PHP version, but I appreciate for certain set-ups (e.g. Linux with package managers) this isn't so easy.*

Comment: Applies from [PHP 7.0.0 onwards](https://3v4l.org/vkhHo) as a warning; strict standards in prior versions - See [changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.error-handling.strict)

Comment: I suspect something in the symfony error handling is picking it up and treating it as a "compile error"

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you for your comments. What you're saying is that I'm at fault for the way I wrote the function in the base class. You should put that as an answer though so I can accept it.